# Logging with Serilog on .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, .net-core, serilog

I am working with Serilog for the first time and I read a couple of tutorials and it doesn't write on DB

this is my Program.cs file where I wrote the configurations:

```
public class Program
{
    public async static Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        await host.RunAsync();
    }



    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        var configSettings = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        Log.Logger = new Serilog.LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configSettings)
            .CreateLogger();

        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
        {
            config.AddConfiguration(configSettings);
        })
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.AddSerilog();
        })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });

    }
}
```

}

there is no problem while executing and it also created the table when missing but it is not inserting the logs.

```
"Serilog.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "Error",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "MSSqlServer",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": constr,
          "tableName": "Logs",
          "autoCreateSqlTable": true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

this is the config in appjson.

and I consumed the log by adding it in the constructor and calling it on methods and that seems ok as well.

Comment: Could you please tell me how you use the Serilog to log the information? It seems it MinimumLevel is error that means only error message will log into the database.

Comment: that is the problem sir, thank you. you can add an answer and I will approve it as a answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description and settings, I found your Serilog MinimumLevel is error not information.

If you log the information it will not log into the database. You should use log error instead.